# How to monitor upload/download on multiple machines

Tags: networking, windows

There are 3 windows machines on my home network. I'm hard wired to the router while my parents and younger sister are on Wi-Fi.

I’ve noticed the occasional drop in connection speed recently and I have a sneaky feeling my 10 year old sister is doing some ridiculous things on her laptop that’s probably killing the network speed.

Is there a program or app that I can use to see what PC is using the most bandwidth at any given time?

Comment: This isn't really an InfoSec question, but a network load monitoring question. You are looking for router features or a web proxy, and the discussion of either is more of a SuperUser-type question.

Comment: I don't feel like this answer should be downvoted.  It just needs to be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: I voted to migrate to SuperUser, but someone else will have to change their vote to actually migrate it.

Comment: Apologies if I posted in the wrong forum. Honestly I just googled my question and this forum was the top hit. The result I found wasn't quite what I was looking for (at least as far as my limited knowledge goes) so I thought the best course of action was to make a post.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a proxy service to monitor usage. Something like [CCProxy](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/). Pretty sure it’s free for up to 3 users—the three PCs you want to monitor—connecting to a server such as your machine or another always-on PC.

Just set the proxy address for the other 3 computers and you’re good.

It's worth re-iterating though, that the server needs to be on *always*.